# Process a dataclass argument with a function before its assignation as an instance attribute

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am working with a dataclass and I construct instances of this dataclass by passing a json dictionary to its constructor. Some of the fields of this dictionary represent dates by a string (but this is not the issue here).
Is there a way to catch and process those fields (in this case: transform them in python datetime objects) before storing them as dataclass attributes?

To be clearer:
If I worked with a classic class, here what I would do:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, dt: str):
        self.dt = datetime.strptime(dt, my_date_format)
```

Now, how should I amend the code below so that it behaves as the code above?

```
@dataclass
class A:
    dt: str = ""
```

My first hope was to use `dataclasses.field` but I found nothing in the doc that does what I want.

2 solutions I would like to avoid:

- using a `__post_init__` action: python coding taught me 1-line solutions often exist...
- altering my dictionary before constructing the dataclass instance with it. All the machinery should be kept inside the class definition (encapsulation).

Answer (score 1):

I would keep `__init__` "dumb": it takes a `datetime` object and just sets the attribute with it.

Add a *class* method to preprocess a string to get the `datetime` object in the first place before creating a new instance.

```
@dataclass
class A:
    dt: datetime

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, dt):
        return cls(datetime.strptime(dt, my_date_format))
```

Comment: I think I understand your code. But what if the class contains n attributes to preprocess instead of one? Is your code still usable? thanks

Comment: plus other attributes to be kept as they are

Comment: In general, `__init__` is *not* the place to preprocess arguments; the caller should be responsible for providing the expected argument. One alternative is to define a *property* which can do the preprocessing in its setter, though that will apply to all assignments, not just the initialization.

Comment: You can also accept whatever arguments you want to a class method and preprocess all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with third-party libraries to simplify creation of a dataclass instance, I would suggest checking out the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) for this task.

Simple example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class A(JSONWizard):
    dt: datetime


a = A.from_json('{"dt": "2021-01-02T13:10:52"}')

print(repr(a))  # A(dt=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 2, 13, 10, 52))
```

It is possible to easily set custom [date-time patterns](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/patterned_date_time.html) as well (with fallback to parse ISO format string):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard, DateTimePattern


@dataclass
class A(JSONWizard):
    dt: DateTimePattern['%m/%d/%y %H.%M.%S']


a = A.from_dict({'dt': '1/02/23 02.03.52'})

print(repr(a))  # A(dt=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 2, 3, 52))
```